# Https webservice call from android

Tags: android, https

I have a Https webservice which has user id and password as authentication type. How do I call this webservice and pass on the user id and the password. I am ok to hardcode  the user id/password.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suppose [this](http://androidsamples.blogspot.com/2009/06/how-to-use-http-connection-saxparser.html) can help you

Search in the forum. There are a lot of articles about Android + Web Service and so on...